# Is there a way to check if something is not in PATH, then conditionally do certain action in CMD?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file, compression

This works great for downloading 7zr for doing decompression tasks in a batch script if 7z.exe isn't in the working directory.

```
if not exist "7z.exe" curl -L "https://www.7-zip.org/a/7zr.exe" -o 7z.exe
```

But what if I have 7-zip installed and 7z.exe is in the PATH. I would prefer to skip downloading 7zr in that case, then continue with the decompression tasks.

Edit: This use case is just an example. My intention is to distribute batch scripts that download required stuff **if** necessary.

Comment: Use the existing 7z.exe.

Comment: [Where - locate files - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/where.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can check the registry entry and check the errolevel that will return from this query :

```
Reg Query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\7-Zip" /v "Path"
```

---

And here is a whole example that check for the path of **7-zip** in the registry and if it not exist he download it.

```bat
@echo off
Title check the path of 7-Zip 
Call :Check_7Zip
echo "%EXE_7Z_PATH%"
if not exist "%EXE_7Z_PATH%" Call :Download7Zip
pause & exit /b
::-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:Check_7Zip
Reg Query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\7-Zip" /v "Path">nul 2>&1
If [%errorlevel%] EQU [1] (Call :Download7Zip
    ) else (
    @FOR /f "tokens=2*" %%i in ('Reg Query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\7-Zip" /v "Path" 2^>nul') do (Set "EXE_7Z_PATH=%%j7z.exe")
)
Exit /B
::-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:Download7Zip
curl -L "https://www.7-zip.org/a/7zr.exe" -o 7z.exe
Exit /B
::------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Ignore my previous comment.  I am being stupid this morning.  This is REALLY nice work but still doesn't answer how to tell if something is in the actual path.

Answer (score 1):

If not exist 7z.exe in PATH try this:

```
where /q 7z.exe || curl -L "https://www.7-zip.org/a/7zr.exe" -o 7z.exe
```

If 7z.exe already exists just output the 7z.exe path and if not exist it will running `curl -L "https://www.7-zip.org/a/7zr.exe" -o 7z.exe`:

```
where 7z.exe 2>nul || curl -L "https://www.7-zip.org/a/7zr.exe" -o 7z.exe
```

Example

```
C:> where /q 7z.exe || curl -L "https://www.7-zip.org/a/7zr.exe" -o 7z.exe
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  564k  100  564k    0     0   240k      0  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:--  240k

C:\>set "path=%cd%;%path%"
C:\>where 7z.exe
C:\7z.exe
```